# a question in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, combinations

Suppose that I have two equal-size multisets of strictly-positive numbers $A=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,...,b_n\}$. I define $A^2=\{a_i\cdot a_j: \forall a_i,a_j \in A\}$ and similarly $B^2$. Is the following necessarily true: If $A \ne B$ then $A^2 \ne B^2$?

Comment: sorry ... my first time to this site. you are totally correct. sometimes when you have a question in mind, the extra conditions are obvious to you and you forget to explicitly state them.

Comment: so do you know the answer to the revised question?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can take $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{-1\}$.

In the case where the numbers are all strictly positive you can take $A=\{1,1,2,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2,2,2\}$, you have $A^2=B^2$.

Comment: and if all numbers are strictly positive?

Comment: In this case you can take $A=\{1,1,2,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2,2,2\}$, you have $A^2=B^2$

Comment: $A^2$ is a multiset as well ... the answer is no ... my office mate just proved it (break into cases if the minimal number is equal or different and recurse by induction)

Comment: @zwim it's ok, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Let a be the minimum of A, and b the min of B. w.l.og. assume $a\leq b$. If $a\neq b$, then the answer is clearly no since $a^2 < b^2$. If $a=b$ look at the next minimal number in both $A$ and $B$ and repeat the argument.